# RH software collections enable for command run with sudo

Tags: sudo, bashrc, profile, scl

We are using RH software collections for python34 and have the following in `/etc/profile.d/scl_enable_python34.sh`

```
source scl_source enable rh-python34
```

This works perfectly for interactive users.

But is there a way to enable the python34 software collection to scripts/commands run through `sudo`?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and using `sudo -i` made scl installed tools usable with sudo.

This is straight from the manpages:

> "The -i (simulate initial login) option runs the shell specified by
>   the password database entry of the target user as a login shell.  This
>                    means that login-specific resource files such as .profile or .login will be read by the shell.  If a command is
>   specified, it is passed to
>                    the shell for execution via the shell's -c option.  If no command is specified, an interactive shell is executed.  sudo
>   attempts to change
>                    to that user's home directory before running the shell.  The security policy shall initialize the environment to a
>   minimal set of vari‐
>                    ables, similar to what is present when a user logs in.  The Command Environment section in the sudoers(5) manual
>   documents how the -i
>                    option affects the environment in which a command is run when the sudoers policy is in use."